# How do I make the `groovy` command exit non-zero for failing JUnit4 tests?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit

When running JUnit tests with the `groovy` command using the built-in automatic test runner, it exits `0` even when tests fail.  I'd like the command to exit non-zero if there are test failures.  Is there a way I can do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import org.junit.*

class BasicTest {

  @Test
  void test_failure() {
    assert false
  }
}
```

```
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 3.0.2 JVM: 13.0.2 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

$ groovy basic_test.groovy
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 1, Time: 8
Test Failure: test_failure(BasicTest)
Assertion failed:

assert false


        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:434)
        ...

$ echo $?
0
```

Thanks folks!

Comment: probably you have to implement own test case runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not seen people running tests like that before...  (writing them as a *nix script)

You can do this though, to catch a failure, and exiting with 1

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import org.junit.*
import org.junit.rules.*

class BasicTest {

  @Rule
  public TestRule watchman = [
    failed: {e, d -> 
      println d
      e.printStackTrace()
      System.exit(1)
    }
  ] as TestWatcher

  @Test
  void test_failure() {
    assert false
  }

}
```

Comment: Yep, we're doing this in a wacky way that we thought would be "simpler" than using Gradle/Maven/etc, and the tests test Jenkins pipelines so things are wacky to begin with :). This does the trick for now, thanks so much!